# How often do I have to ask google to crawl my website?

Tags: web, indexing, web-crawler

I created a website in the month of September. I couldn't find it on google so I researched and figured it out that I've to index my website with the help of google search console. I requested Google to crawl my website but I'm confused about how often do I have to ask google to crawl my website? and how long will Google take to index my website on search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this google support article it can take from a few days to a few weeks until your website gets (re)indexed by google.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Comment: Thank You Andreas...I have one more question...Do I have to ask google to crawl my website everytime I upload a new blog ?

Comment: If google "figured out" that you website is a blog it should automatically re-crawl it at unknown intervals.